# Wordpress: Add custom ID to final li in wp_nav_menu

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I'm using three primary navs in my theme and I'm attempting to place a final link to the menu with a custom ID across all primary navs.

This is what I'm going for:

```
<nav id="menu" role="navigation" class="menu-primary">
  <ul id="nav" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-418" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-418"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-474" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-474"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-463" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-463"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-416" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-416"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li id="back" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-491"><href="#header">back</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see, the final li has an ID of 'back'. Any idea how I can accomplish this without the use of js? I can see how I can change classes, but not ID's. I'm doing this for CSS purposes.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Am I right in saying you are trying to apply the same id to the last link in three menus? An id should be used only once, you should use a class if its being assigned three times. If you are not referencing it via JS then why do you need it to be an id?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the `id` you can insert/inject another `menu item/li` at last as a custom menu item like following

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item');
function your_custom_menu_item ($items)
{
    $items .= '<li id="back" class="what-ever"><a href="#">Back</a></li>';
    return $items;
}
```

Just paste the code snippet in your `functions.php` and it will add a custom `menu item` in your menu. Hope this helps.

Also there is another way to alter the `menu` using a custom `walker` and [here is a nice example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `wp_nav_menu`, then the best way would be to use the classes provided by Wordpress. I don't think there's a way to add specific id's to menu items.

Unless you do this with jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use JS/jQuery to do this.  WordPress menus are dynamically written and you can't just get in the theme file and edit the li's.

If your menus are not on the same page then you can use an ID and the first example. You would need to change the #nav to the ID of the UL for each menu and reiterate that one line 3 times, once for each menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#nav li').last().attr('id', 'back');
});
```

If your menus are on the same page you'll need to use a class like below.  You would need to change the #nav to the ID of the UL for each menu and reiterate that one line 3 times, once for each menu.  That is unless all the menus have a class on the UL, in which case you could just use `$('#classNameHere li').last().addClass('back');`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#nav li').last().addClass('back');
});
```